# javascript, html onclick change variable

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I have a series of links, each belonging to different products with different prices.

Eg:

```
<%a class="items" href="order.htm" alt="" onclick="javascript: num = 149.99">Content<%/a>
```

After a user clicks one of the product links, I would like to be able to display the price of that specific product on the Order page. Is it possible to hold the changed variable for use on the separate Order page? If so, how?

This is purely for my personal exploration into JavaScript and HTML5.

Edit: Okay, so using sessionStorage, I can set and get variables.

Eg:

```
myVar = window.sessionStorage;
myVar.setItem("key", "149.99");
```

Now, how would I integrate the var with the product link, then call that var on the following page?

Comment: Did you try something? Can you show us some test? Maybe some code?

Comment: Please do not store price information in the browser. You **will** run into a situation where people can buy everything in your store for free and get $5 back for their effort. All data that should not be tampered with, like the contents of a shopping cart, should always remain stored safely on the server side, and passed back to the client with each page reload.

Comment: Thanks for the information. However, this is simply for a prototype and would not be used for any monetary transactions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are creating a shopping page, I would definitely recommend you to include some PHP.
With only JS and HTML, you will encounter many problems you will have to find a workaround for.

Use a server-side storage like PHP's `$_SESSION` superglobal. Any client storage could get manipulated. You are saying you aren't publishing it, but keep it clean anyways and don't learn yourself the worse way.

Anyways, if you just wanna get this working, here are the commands to store the data and get it afterwards:

```
//store data on the initial page using setItem()
sessionStorage.setItem("mykey", "Some Value");

//on the next page get it with getItem() and declare it as a var
var persistedval = sessionStorage.getItem("mykey");
­
//Now you can write the price to the document using the variable
document.write("Total is: " + persistedval);
```

Values can be set and retrieved using either getItem() and setItem(), or by directly referencing the key as a property of the object, like in my example above.

But remember, sessionStorage isn't very safe, since it's stored in the browser session.

Imagine you even forgot your price validaton check and some 'hacker' manipulates the data and changes the price from `45,99` to `-249,99` and the product name to `Credit note`.

If you want to go deeper into shopping pages, user areas, etc. you should concentrate on HTML+PHP at first and just use JS when you need it (which will be mostly DOM-Manipulation when you start off).

But it's great for storing a user login, any user-specific data or insensitive data, no question about that.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. So, with the sessionStorage setters and getters, I set the value of the variable, then get the value of that variable on the next page with something like document.write("Total is: " + sessionStorage.getItem("key")); ?

Comment: Whew, that helped quite a bit. Thank you, sir.

Answer (score 2):

You could store your cart using [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Storage)

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I will check out localStorage.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript has no notion of state, so by itself it cannot persist information across pages. However, there are several different ways that we can remember data from one page to another.

We could use a [cookie](http://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-deal-with-cookies-in-javascript/) if really really have only a very small amount of data to store and want to support old browsers.

Another way to do it would be to use [LocalStorage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html) to store the information. This gives a much greater amount of storage space and has a flexible and easy to use format to set and retrieve the data.